# how to stop bash from returning wildcard when pattern doesn match?

Tags: bash, for-loop, glob

When pattern match this code work as intended:

```
mkdir -p mytestdir001
for f in "mytestdir???"; do
  echo $f
done
```

but when I replace wildcard so no item will be matched the for loop returns the wildcard.

Is there a way to prevent this other than checking in the loop if `f` variable is equal to initial wildcard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `nullglob` option.

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for f in *notfound ; do echo "$f" ; done
$
```